# How to specify memory and cpu's for a Jupyter spark/pyspark notebook from command line?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

The intention is to achieve something along the lines of

```
 jupyter-notebook --kernel-options="--mem 1024m --cpus 4"
```

Where `kernel-options` would be forwarded to the `pyspark` or `spark` kernels.

We need this in order to run separate jupyter servers - one for `pyspark` kernel and one for `spark (in scala)` kernel on the same machine.  That is a requirement since a single `jupyter` server does not support simultaneous `pyspark` and `(scala) spark` kernels running concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Jupyter 4.0 and later you should be able to start a Spark-enabled notebooks like this:

```
pyspark [options]
```

where [options] is the list of any flags you pass to pyspark.

For this to work, you would need to set following environmental variables in your `.profile`:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="/path/to/my/bin/jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/path/to/my/bin/python"
```

Alternatively, if you are using Apache Toree, you could pass them via SPARK_OPTS:

```
SPARK_OPTS='--master=local[4]' jupyter notebook
```

More details on Apache Toree [setup](https://toree.incubator.apache.org/documentation/user/installation.html).